# Update tkinter canvas widget on button click

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to call a function on a button click which will call second function that updates the fill color of an oval. I am getting an error that the object doesnt have the attribute. The goal of the program will be to eventually update the the signal light colors as variables linked to each go from 0 to 1 but right now i'm just getting the back end working. I have looked at dozens of examples over the last two days and cant get this to work.

```
import tkinter as tk


class WaysideSimulator(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        # self.pack()
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Draw Buttons
        self.Start_Simulation_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Start Simulation", command=self.start_simulation)
        self.Start_Simulation_Button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.End_Simulation_Button = tk.Button(self, text="End Simulation", fg="red", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.End_Simulation_Button.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # Top Signal Buttons
        self.Top_Red_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Set Top Signal Red", command=self.set_top_red)
        self.Top_Red_Button.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.Top_Yellow_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Set Top Signal Yellow", command=self.set_top_yellow)
        # self.Searchlight_Button.pack(side="bottom")
        self.Top_Yellow_Button.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.Top_Green_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Set Top Signal Green", command=self.set_top_green)
        self.Top_Green_Button.grid(row=4, column=0)

        self.Top_Black_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Set Top Signal Black", command=self.set_top_off)
        self.Top_Black_Button.grid(row=5, column=0)

        # Middle Signal Buttons
        self.Middle_Red_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Set Middle Signal Red", command=self.set_middle_red)
        self.Middle_Red_Button.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.Middle_Yellow_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Set Middle Signal Yellow", command=self.set_middle_yellow)
        self.Middle_Yellow_Button.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.Middle_Green_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Set Middle Signal Green", command=self.set_middle_green)
        self.Middle_Green_Button.grid(row=4, column=1)

        self.Middle_Black_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Set Middle Signal Black", command=self.set_middle_black)
        self.Middle_Black_Button.grid(row=5, column=1)

        # Bottom Signal Buttons
        self.Bottom_Red_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Set Bottom Signal Red", command=self.set_bottom_red)
        self.Bottom_Red_Button.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.Bottom_Yellow_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Set Bottom Signal Yellow", command=self.set_bottom_yellow)
        self.Bottom_Yellow_Button.grid(row=3, column=2)

        self.Bottom_Green_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Set Bottom Signal Green", command=self.set_bottom_green)
        self.Bottom_Green_Button.grid(row=4, column=2)

        self.Bottom_Black_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Set Bottom Signal Black", command=self.set_bottom_black)
        self.Bottom_Black_Button.grid(row=5, column=2)

        # Draw the Canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=500, height=500, bg="white")
        self.canvas.grid()

        # Draw the Searchlight Signal Heads
        self.signal_pole = self.canvas.create_rectangle(245, 20, 255, 500, fill="grey")

        self.top_signal_head = self.canvas.create_oval(200, 10, 300, 110, fill="black")
        self.middle_signal_head = self.canvas.create_oval(200, 160, 300, 260, fill="black")
        self.bottom_signal_head = self.canvas.create_oval(200, 310, 300, 410, fill="black")

        self.top_signal_light = self.canvas.create_oval(240, 50, 260, 70, fill="red", tags="top_light")
        self.top_signal_light_ON = True
        self.middle_signal_light_ON = self.canvas.create_oval(240, 200, 260, 220, fill="yellow", tags="middle_light")
        self.middle_light_ON = True
        self.bottom_signal_light = self.canvas.create_oval(240, 350, 260, 370, fill="green", tags="bottom_light")
        self.bottom_signal_light_ON = True

    # Function Definitions

    def set_top_red(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("top_light", fill="Red")
        self.top_signal_light_ON = True
        print("Top signal is RED")

    def set_top_yellow(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("top_light", fill="yellow")
        self.top_signal_light_ON = True
        print("Top signal is YELLOW")

    def set_top_green(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("top_light", fill="green")
        self.top_signal_light_ON = True
        print("Top signal is GREEN.")

    def set_top_off(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("top_light", fill="black")
        self.top_signal_light_ON = False
        print("Top signal is OFF.")

    def set_middle_red(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("middle_light", fill="Red")
        self.middle_light_ON = True
        print("Middle signal is RED")

    def set_middle_yellow(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("middle_light", fill="yellow")
        self.middle_light_ON = True
        print("middle signal is YELLOW")

    def set_middle_green(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("middle_light", fill="green")
        self.middle_light_ON = True
        print("Middle signal is GREEN.")

    def set_middle_black(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("middle_light", fill="black")
        self.middle_light_ON = False
        print("Middle signal is OFF.")

    def set_bottom_red(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("bottom_light", fill="Red")
        self.middle_light_ON = True
        print("Bottom signal is RED")

    def set_bottom_yellow(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("bottom_light", fill="yellow")
        self.middle_light_ON = True
        print("Bottom signal is YELLOW")

    def set_bottom_green(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("bottom_light", fill="green")
        self.middle_light_ON = True
        print("Bottom signal is GREEN.")

    def set_bottom_black(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("bottom_light", fill="black")
        self.middle_light_ON = False
        print("Bottom signal is OFF.")

    # Simulation Functions
    def start_simulation(self):
        print("Searchlight Simulation Started")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("top_light", fill="black")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("middle_light", fill="black")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("bottom_light", fill="black")
        self.top_signal_light_ON = False
        self.middle_signal_light_ON = False
        self.bottom_signal_light_ON = False
        print("All signals are OFF")



def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Searchlight Simulator")
    root.geometry("500x650")
    # root.resizable(0, 0)
    s1 = WaysideSimulator(master=root)
    s1.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: First, `command=self.start_simulation()` should be `command=self.start_simulation` (without the `()`).

Comment: Should a `else` block be included inside `update_lights()` function?

Comment: Please show the actual error.

Comment: I was able to fix it. Thank you acw1668 those errors were the problem. I've update my code in main section with the working code for anyone who finds this later.